# How to parse a table column with multiple elements using Cheerio?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, cheerio

I have a table as shown below:

```html
<table>
  <tr class="odd">
    <td>some text</td>
    <td>
      data I want
      <div>some elements</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="even">
    <td>some text</td>
    <td>
      data I want
      <div>some elements</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Using:

```
$("tr.odd:nth-child(1) > td:nth-child(2)").text()
```

I am getting the text available inside the `div` tag also.  But I need only the text data I want.

How can get that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it would be simpler to `remove()` the `<div>`s and then parsing the data.

```
$("tr td > div").remove()
$("tr.odd:nth-child(1) > td:nth-child(2)").text()
```